# How to load php page with fancybox?

Tags: php, fancybox

I searched a lot but I can't find an answer.

In my contact.php I have this code:

```
<a class="mailform" href="submit.php">Click</a>
```

I have this script, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.mailform').click(function() {
     $.fancybox(
        {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'ajax'   : {
              cache   : false,
              url     : this.href
             }
        }
    );
});
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to be more specific about 'not working'

Comment: Should the page "submit.php" be loaded in fancybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false to stop the link from following through

```
$('.mailform').click(function() {

     var myUrl = $(this).attr('href');

     $.fancybox(
        {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'             : 350,
            'height'            : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'ajax'   : {
              cache   : false,
              url     : myUrl
             }
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

Comment: when I do that it shows this message: http://prntscr.com/7qhh7

Comment: I've updated it to show how you can pass the URL (You may need to pass a full URL too, not too sure on how fancybox wants them)

Comment: @BenGriffiths The `ajax` object is a standard `$.ajax` object, fancybox just overwrites the `success` and `error` handlers. So any URL that will work with jQ should work with fancybox

Comment: It shows the same message, I'm not understanding what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem here is related to the scope of the magic `this` variable. In your code, `this` is referring to the object literal that you have assigned to `'ajax':`. In order to do what I think you are trying to do, you will need another temporary variable. By convention, we call the variable `that`. You also need to return `false` from your click handler, stop stop the browser from following the link in the main window.

```
$('.mailform').click(function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the <a> DOM element, so we create a copy of it
    // and store it in `that`
    var that = this;
    $.fancybox({
        // Now `this` refers to the object you are passing to fancybox()
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'width'         : 350,
        'height'        : 'auto',
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'ajax'          : {
            // Now `this` refers to the object you are assigning to 'ajax':
            cache   : false,
            url     : that.href // Use `that` instead of `this`
        }
    });
    // We also need to return false, to stop the browser following the link
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The Fancybox says that "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later"

Comment: Look in your web server logs - do you see a request for `submit.php` with an error code result?