# can any one tell me why this happens with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

![enter image description here][1]

```
$jq2(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

to load page in fancybox then this does not work but if i use

```
$jq2(".fancybox").click(function() {
  $jq2("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);

  var selected_form = $jq2(this).attr('rel');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../pages/ajaxcontent/ajax_partner_reg.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      id: selected_form,
      utility: 'getvardata'
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });
  $jq2.fancybox.open('#verification_form');
});
```

then it works can anyone tell difference?
and if it is possible to load page directly in fancybox than 
it will best for me bcoz i have so many operations on that page to do

Comment: yahh it is for i m using 2 version of jquery in my project
by  <script>var $jq2 = $.noConflict( true );</script>

Comment: If this works `$jq2.fancybox.open('#verification_form');` then why not use it elsewhere?

Comment: might be this will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010390/how-to-load-php-page-with-fancybox

Comment: Guruprasad Rao sir it work well if i use that  $jq2.fancybox.open('#verification_form'); but if i do that than i have to
get data through ajax than load page on header and than  put data in that form through jquery 
wait i will post a pic of what i want to do

Comment: ur top code simply adds the fancybox event handlers to the element, making it so when u click `.fancybox` it will open a fancybox with the content of whatever is in the `href` attribute. the second block invokes a fancybox directly w the `.open` method, plus whatever else the `ajax` call is doing.

Comment: try `$jq2.fancybox($jq2('#verification_form'))`

Comment: what is the significance of the ajax call in there?

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/d7nEA1cG6d73KrSL7
https://goo.gl/photos/eq17otzJbo24thuu6

Comment: checkout that photos

Comment: if you want to load the whole form using an ajax, then its very simple. `$.fancybox({
        href: '/some/url-to-load',
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: selected_form, utility: 'getvardata'}
    });`

Comment: or else if you want to use the retrun json from your ajax,

`$.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: '../pages/ajaxcontent/ajax_partner_reg.php',
                          dataType: "json",
                          data: {id: selected_form, utility: 'getvardata'},
                          success: function (data) {
/*here code to fill the data in #verification_form*/
$jq2.fancybox.open('#verification_form');
                          }
                      });`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to fill the data from AJAX call retrun JSON into a form and then open that form in fancybox. If that is the case, the following code will work. Look at the fancybox [documentations](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs).

Open the fancybox in the ajax call back after filling the form in `#verification_form`. Like the following.

```
$jq2(".fancybox").click(function () {
    $jq2("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);

    var selected_form = $jq2(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../pages/ajaxcontent/ajax_partner_reg.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            id: selected_form,
            utility: 'getvardata'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //here goes the code to fill the form before open
            $jq2.fancybox.open($jq2('#verification_form'));
        }
    });
});
```